# Trained Random forest model from python to matlab

Tags: python, matlab, model, regression, random-forest

I have a model using random forest developed in python. Now i want to use this trained network in Matlab . How to take trained network from python to matlab. Can someone please let me know how to do that

I tried to save the trained model in pkl file then tried to load it in matlab but it didnt work

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the code of the steps you have already taken so that we can help you solve your problem.